# Cancel A Specific Reminder for App Store Update

Tags: mac-appstore, server.app

I have a Mac Mini server. I bought it with Mountain Lion OSX and Server 2.2.2.

I do not use my mac mini as a server anymore, I just use it as a desktop and use a NAS for my local server. I did not want to pay for the upgrade to Server.app version 3.

The app store keeps reminding me there is an update for the Apple server program but when I tried to update it it told me I'm not eligible for it because I don't have Mavericks OS, the most current OS version. The update reminder for the server app has been up there for a couple of weeks and I'd like it to go away.

Is there any way to cancel the update reminder for this one specific update that I am not eligible for? I do not want to turn off the service completely cause I still want to know about updates for all my other programs/apps.

Answer (score 1):

Mavericks is free and doesn't cost anything to update to.  If you are satisfied with staying at Mountain Lion you can ignore any update for server.app version 3 by opening **terminal.app** and running..

```
softwareupdate --list
```

to get the full name of the update and then run..

```
softwareupdate --ignore <label>
```

If you due end up running the free upgrade to Mavericks you can clear any updates you ignored by running..

```
softwareupdate --reset-ignored
```

Comment: Mavericks **Server**, which is what the question is about, is not free.